# What are the necessary and sufficient constraints on the world-to-mind direction of fit?

Tags: rationality, intentionality

A [glossary](http://johnmacfarlane.net/135/glossary.html) that [John MacFarlane](http://johnmacfarlane.net/) keeps defines **direction of fit** like so:

> **direction of fit:** The direction of the “match” between the world and an intentional state or speech act that is required for the latter
>   to be satisfied. [...] For intentional states, direction of fit is
>   either mind-to-world (the content of the mental state must match the
>   world, as with beliefs) or world-to-mind (the world must be made to
>   match the content of the mental state, as with intentions and
>   desires).

It doesn't seem difficult to determine the *appropriate* nature of our **mind-to-world** intentional states. Their appropriate nature is that they match accurately and precisely to the world, perhaps maximally so (except where perhaps this doesn't infringe excessively on most others' privacy). It feels as if this is an obvious and undeniable logical definition.

However, it seems much more difficult to determine the appropriate nature of our **world-to-mind** intentional states. Their appropriate nature is... what? While one good first answer might be that their appropriate nature is that they reflect end-states that already have well-defined routines for satisfying them, we know this answer comes up short. We regularly see people solve problems that at least in large part had no known well-defined routines for satisfying them. This meant that they posed a problem that hadn't been posed exactly like it before (or finally solved one that had been such an open problem).

What exactly is the permissibilic mechanism for people to pose unique (previously unsatisfied) problems, unique world-to-mind intentional states? Sometimes people pose unique problems and other people like them for it, and sometimes people pose unique problems and other people hate them for it. Many people act as though they have a thoroughgoing familiarity of the permissibilic mechanism, that here too there's an obvious and undeniable logical definition in effect.

But where's the manual – or what is it like – on the necessary and sufficient constraints on posing previously unsatisfied problems, on formulating previously unsatisfied world-to-mind intentional states?